# AWS Athena disable cache

Tags: amazon-athena

I am in the process of comparing the performance of CSV and Parquet files in AWS Athena.

To ensure that I do not get a considerable reduction in the execution times of two consecutive runs of the same query, I would like to make sure that the cache is disabled.

Do we know if there is a solution for this?
Or if AThena doesn’t even have cache enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

How Athena configures the presto engine behind is totally out of our control. I have throughly tested Aws Athena and  from my finding it doens't  cache the data. I see that same query executed consecutively takes similar amount of time and data scan.

But Parquet should definitely give you better performance and lesser data scan for cost efficiency.

Comment: Thanks Kalyan. Just curious if there is any documentation around that available online.